# radio buttons check and uncheck remove and replace input values

Tags: copy, radio-button, checked

I have two radio buttons with label name A & B and two groups of text boxes with class names groupA and groupB.My requirement is When user checks radiobutton A then all the values from Group B text boxes will clear and when user checks Radiobutton B then GroupB text boxes again fill with their original values and Group A textboxes values will clear vice versa. For this i am able to clear textboxes values based on class.But i how to fill all the previous values when user checks one of the radiobutton?Below is my code.

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery("#id1").click(function() {     
            jQuery(".groupB").each(function()
            {
               jQuery('input.groupB[type="text"]').val('');
            });
        }
    });

jQuery("#id2").click(function() {     
            jQuery(".groupA").each(function()
            {
               jQuery('input.groupA[type="text"]').val('');
            });
        }
    });

});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you create a working version of your code on jsfiddle.net? An approach I would take is to store previous values of the text boxes in hidden fields.

Comment: Hi, I am sorry about this, because i don't know how to do this on jsfiddle.net. Thanks for your quick resposne.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: jQuery version 1.10.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't show your HTML, so I'm not sure I have the fields right. But here is what I came up with:

```
<body>
  <form>
    <input id="id1" type="radio" name="test" value="A" />Group A
    <input type="hidden" name="hidden_a1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="hidden_a2" />
    <input class="groupA" type="text" name="text_a1" disabled="disabled" />
    <input class="groupA" type="text" name="text_a2" disabled="disabled" />
    <br />
    <input id="id2" type="radio" name="test" value="B" />Group B
    <input type="hidden" name="hidden_b1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="hidden_b2" />
    <input class="groupB" type="text" name="text_b1" disabled="disabled" />
    <input class="groupB" type="text" name="text_b2" disabled="disabled" />
  </form>
</body>
```

and here is the JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#id1').on('click', {
    show: 'A',
    hide: 'B'
  }, choose_group);
  $('#id2').on('click', {
    show: 'B',
    hide: 'A'
  }, choose_group);
});

function choose_group(event) {
  $('.group' + event.data.show).each(function(index) {
    $(this).prop('value', $('[name="' + $(this).prop('name').replace('text', 'hidden') + '"]').prop('value'));
    $(this).prop('disabled', false);
  });
  $('.group' + event.data.hide).each(function(index) {
    $('[name="' + $(this).prop('name').replace('text', 'hidden') + '"]').prop('value',
      $(this).prop('value'));
    $(this).prop('value', '');
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
  });
}
```